# Encrypted result in java and cryptoJS are different

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt AES using java and cryptoJS, everything good if i encrypt and decrypt a short text in either way. But if i put a long text, the result is wrong when cryptoJS try to decrypt it, in other way is working fine. Please help me to answer my problem. Here is my code.

**java code**

```
public void setKey(String myKey){
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(myKey), "AES");
    }

public String generateKey(int len) {
        final String AB = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        Random rnd = new Random();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sb.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

public void encrypt(String strToEncrypt)
    {
        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/Iso10126Padding");

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);


            setEncryptedString(Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: "+e.toString());
        }
    }
    public void decrypt(String strToDecrypt)
    {
        try
        {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/Iso10126PADDING");

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt))));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: "+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

**Javascript code**

```
function encrypt(string,key){
    var keyInside = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(string, keyInside, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Iso10126});
    return encrypted;
  }
function decrypt(string,key){
  var keyInside = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(string, keyInside, {mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Iso10126});
  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
function generateKey(length)
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for( var i=0; i < length; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    return text;
}
```

thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Do you have an example that fails + the key you used?

Comment: thanks, it's solved. it's because of the whitespace in the chiper text. When i remove the whitespace. it works :)